# how do i sort lines in bash?

Tags: bash, sorting

I am currently having some problems with my script not sorting my files.

The error seem to be localized here where i sort the utt2spk file, which is done like this..

```
for x in test train; do
        for f in text utt2spk; do
            sort data/$x/$f -o data/$x/$f
        done
done
```

I have a function which checks whether the file is sorted, or has duplicates. The function checks like this:

```
function check_sorted_and_uniq {
  ! awk '{print $1}' $1 | sort | uniq | cmp -s - <(awk '{print $1}' $1) && \
    echo "$0: file $1 is not in sorted order or has duplicates" && exit 1;
}
```

and it always triggers the error message..

The problem with this for - loop is that it doesn't sort the numbers correctly.  In this case i am having the text

```
fkdo-b-cen6 fkdo
fkdo-b-cen7 fkdo
fkdo-b-cen8 fkdo
flrp-b-an2121 flrp
flrp-b-an21 flrp
flrp-b-an22 flrp
flrp-b-an23 flrp
flrp-b-an24 flrp
flrp-b-an25 flrp
flrp-b-cen1 flrp
```

which should have been

```
fkdo-b-cen6 fkdo
fkdo-b-cen7 fkdo
fkdo-b-cen8 fkdo
flrp-b-an21 flrp
flrp-b-an22 flrp
flrp-b-an23 flrp
flrp-b-an24 flrp
flrp-b-an25 flrp
flrp-b-an2121 flrp
flrp-b-cen1 flrp
```

So why isn't it sorting it correctly?, and how does I make it sort correctly?

If this can be done in some other way, it would be ok aswell, i just need to be able to execute it in bash script.

```
sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

Comment: As per the definition of *lexicographically*, your `flrp-b-an2121 flrp` should be before `flrp-b-an22 flrp`. For sorting lexicographically, you have to just do: `<something> | sort`

Comment: It looks like you're sorting the data in groups, not all at once.  You should probably be piping it to sort instead of doing it in a loop

Comment: Well, do you want to sort lexicographically, or do you want numeric sort? Because they *are* lexicographically sorted. Sounds like you want numeric; use `sort -n`.

Comment: There are several options to sort that control numeric sorting. See the man page at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html. Specifically, check out the `-g`, `-h`, and `-n` options.

Comment: Can you see if you have `GNU sort`? from `sort --version` output ?

Comment: added i bit more information to provide a bit more context.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Are you sure about that... 2121 > 25 ? 
Lexiographical i both alphabetical and numerical order..

Comment: @CarltonBanks: I mentioned 22 instead of 25. Lexicographically I guess `"2121"` is before `"22"` if sorting ASCENDING :)

Comment: @CarltonBanks: Check my solution below to see if solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is what GNU sort calls `-V`, `--version-sort`

> natural sort of (version) numbers within text

So you just have to use `sort -V …` in your `for` loop as well as in the `function check_sorted_and_uniq`.